# Pytest in a nested directory

Tags: python, pytest

This example works if `tool_1/` is the top folder.
However, I must make room in the repo for other tools, as so:

```
tool_repo/tool_1/src/main.py
tool_repo/tool_1/test/test_main.py
```

I also have:

```
tool_repo/tool_1/__init__.py
tool_repo/tool_1/src/__init__.py
```

```
# main.py
def func():
    print("func")

# test_main.py
from tool_1.src.main import func
def test_func():
    func()
    assert 0
```

```
Running in: tool_repo\tool_1
>python -m pytest
```

Error:

```
ImportError while importing test module 'C:\pycharmProjects\tool_repo\tool_1\test\test_main.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
C:\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\importlib\__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
test\test_main.py:1: in <module>
    from tool_1.src.main import func
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tool_1'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: did you try to run from `tool_repo` folder?

Comment: hmm...that worked. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the module from outside.

If your module `tool_1` located in `tool_repo\tool_1\`, you should run it from:

```
cd C:\pycharmProjects\tool_repo
python -m pytest
```

note that your `imports` looks for it: `import tool_1...`

Comment: @GlaceCelery does it answer? if so, can you please upvote & accept?